# Display a Grid as a comboBox's selectedValue

Tags: wpf, combobox

I was wondering, is it possible to display a grid in a comboBox as its selectedValue (or displayMemberPath) ?

I wanted to do something like that :

[image: ComboBox]

It's a screen from Telerik's comboBox, but I wish to do the same in WPF only. I already use a grid inside the dropdown and it works pretty well, and I'd achieve something cool if I could display many rows as a selectedValue. I supposed I'd use a grid but applying a grid in the displayMemberPath style doesn't really work.

My comboBox is inside a DataGridTemplateColumn but I don't think it matters, just saying.

Thanks !

Comment: not clear what you are asking. Image is not visible

Comment: Ah ? Strange... It works for me. Anyway, my comboBox has a grid in its dropdown, with 2 rows with infos from a dataSet or something. What I would like to know is, if an user selects a value inside this dropdown, is it possible to display these 2 rows as a selectedValue instead of only one as usual ?

Comment: Here's the link to my image : [comboBox](http://imgur.com/enW9H0C)